# Not able to Predict Input from Scanner or Keyboard in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working with angular 6. I just got a problem. i have a text-box and a submit button. i want to add a functionality.Input into text box will be either by keyboard or by Bar-code scanner. after input all text the button should be submit automatically in case of bar-code scanner. If i  go with OnChange or Keypress event then on every character the button is going to submit in both cases. (Keyboard,Barcode scanner).

I have searched also for if i get the event to predict the scanner input or keyboard input then i will do rest of things.

Comment: <input type="text" #searchField maxlength="SearchBy!=='EmailAddress'?17:100"
                                            [formControl]="form.controls['SearchId']"
                                            [ngClass]="(errorMassage!=='' && errorMassage!==undefined)?'form-control errordata':'form-control'"
                                            placeholder={{PlaceholderSearch}} autocomplete="off"
                                            (keypress)="_AllowNumberOnly($event)" (onChange)="SearchOrder($event)">

Comment: I have an input box that a user can scan (handheld scanner) or manually enter(keyboard) a UPC. If the user scans the UPC, I would like to automatically call a search function, but if manually entered, the user will have to hit a search button. I have been able to find solutions for angularJS and jquery however nothing for angular 2+

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

In you html add keyup event.

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp()">
```

Then call your submit function after a timeout like this.

```
onKeyUp() {
    lsetTimeout(() => {
        submitFunction();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Response but this is working same as Keypress and OnChange Event.

Comment: Your text input has a fix length? Do you know the length of that input?

Comment: it may be 5 to 20 digits...Not fixed.

Comment: Have you tried (blur) event? <input type="text" (blur)="onKeyUp()"> Try this and let me know the result.

Comment: Add your codes to the question, Otherwise it is difficult to understand you scenario.

Comment: <input type="text" #searchField maxlength="SearchBy!=='EmailAddress'?17:100"
                                            [formControl]="form.controls['SearchId']"
                                            [ngClass]="(errorMassage!=='' && errorMassage!==undefined)?'form-control errordata':'form-control'"
                                            placeholder={{PlaceholderSearch}} autocomplete="off"
                                             (keyup)="ScanSearchOrder($event)" autofocus="true">

Comment: ScanSearchOrder(event:any)
  {
    debugger;
   setTimeout(() => {
    this.SearchOrder(event);
}, 300);
  }